# String formatting in wx.ListBox

Tags: python, linux, listbox, string-formatting

I'm new to Python and I want to display string with specific format in `wx.ListBox`.

For example: with proper alignment, but It display as below.

[image]

**CODE:**

```
fileName = fileName + str(" " * (38 - len(fileName)))
self.displayList.append( "   %02d             %s  %0.2fKB" % (index+1, fileName, fileSize ))
```

When I Print `self.displayList`, It display with proper alignment.

[image]

Let me know where I am wrong, or what should be other way to display string with proper alignment.

**EDIT**

First thanks for the reply.

By applying your(Sundar Nataraj) solution, Output is same as you mention but its on Console, While in wx.ListBox, again not in proper formatting.

See Below image.

[image]

I just pass displayList as argument.

```
self.autoNcListbox = wx.ListBox(self.autoProgListPanel, wx.ID_ANY, wx.Point( 0, 25), wx.Size( 512, 510 ), self.displayList, wx.RAISED_BORDER)
```

Comment: can you add sample of code how your displaying in wxlist box

Comment: http://zetcode.com/wxpython/advanced/ in this page at bottom u find mixin .. did u try that

Comment: I have looked into, but not find solution of my issue...

Comment: just try code after edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this way,

```
index=[1,2,3,4]
text=['animal','gv','asdfasdfasd','adfasdfasdf']
size=['1kb','2kb','3kb','4kb']
displaylist=[]

for i in zip(index,text,size):
    s=""
    for j in range(0,3):
        s +='{0:{fill}{align}16}'.format(i[j], fill=' ', align='<')

    print s
    displaylist.append(s)

for i in displaylist:
    print i
```

output

```
1                animal           1kb             
2                gv               2kb             
3                asdfasdfasd      3kb             
4                adfasdfasdf      4kb
```

Edit:

```
import wx
import sys
from wx.lib.mixins.listctrl import ListCtrlAutoWidthMixin


index=[1,2,3,4]
text=['animal','gv','asdfasdfasd','adfasdfasdf']
size=['1kb','2kb','3kb','4kb']
displaylist=[]
for i,j,l in zip(index,text,size):
    displaylist.append((i,j,l))




class AutoWidthListCtrl(wx.ListCtrl, ListCtrlAutoWidthMixin):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        wx.ListCtrl.__init__(self, parent, -1, style=wx.LC_REPORT)
        ListCtrlAutoWidthMixin.__init__(self)


class Actresses(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, id, title):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, id, title, size=(380, 230))

        hbox = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)

        panel = wx.Panel(self, -1)

        self.list = AutoWidthListCtrl(panel)
        self.list.InsertColumn(0, 'index', width=140)
        self.list.InsertColumn(1, 'text', width=130)
        self.list.InsertColumn(2, 'filesize', wx.LIST_FORMAT_RIGHT, 90)

        for i in displaylist:
            index = self.list.InsertStringItem(sys.maxint, str(i[0]))
            self.list.SetStringItem(index, 1, i[1])
            self.list.SetStringItem(index, 2, i[2])

        hbox.Add(self.list, 1, wx.EXPAND)
        panel.SetSizer(hbox)

        self.Centre()
        self.Show(True)

app = wx.App()
Actresses(None, -1, 'file')
app.MainLoop()
```

Comment: Not solved the problem...:( Look into EDIT part of the question.